# Curve fitting - is there a way to place more importance on the back end of a curve fit?

Tags: python, scipy, data-science

I have data like so:

```
x    y
1    637.36
2    1684.73
3    2192.15
4    2622.48
5    2926.11
...
60   11253.47
```

I fit an asymptotic curve to the data using the scipy curve fit function.

```
def asymptotic_curve(x, a, b, n):
    return a * x ** n / (x ** n + b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(asymptotic, x, y, p0=[500., 10., 1.])
```

[Graph of Data and Fitted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wJVI.png)

Using values in popt I can estimate y when x = 180. However, if you notice in the diagram the tail end of the fitted curve starts to stray from the data, meaning y will be very inaccurate at x = 180.

Is there a way to place more emphasis on fitting the tail end of the curve?

I'm not expecting anything super precise. Just a better guess. Currently, it overestimates Y at x= 180 by approx 70% (Less than 40% would be fine).

I have tried other types of curves - Asymptotic curves perform best due to the nature of data.

Comment: All data points have the same "weight". What you can try is to add y-errors to the data points which you want to allow to stray further from the fit, which essentially is applying a weight to the samples.

Comment: I guess you could be fitting your data using splines and generalized additive models.

Comment: Are you trying to do extrapolation from your set of data?

Comment: @anatolyg Yes - I want better approximations of Y.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That's not a bad idea. I will see what I can do with the y-errors.

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince uhh.. that looks interesting. I need to read up on those. Never applied it.

Comment: See the accepted answer, `sigma` are the y-errors.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual page for `curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) specifies that it has a `sigma` parameter, which gives it a measure of uncertainty for each point. You should give more uncertainty to your less important points.

Since you are trying to do extrapolation, you might want to *delete* some of your points which are farthest from your target range (mathematically, give them infinite uncertainty, but really, just delete them).

---

Disclaimer: I have never used `curve_fit`; all the above is an educated guess.

Comment: Thank you, adding 'sigma=100/y' and 'absolute_sigma=False' did exactly what you said. The results are much better with added uncertainty.